# Weebly Gallery Lightbox border color

Tags: css, border, lightbox, weebly

Is there anyone who knows how to change the white border when you click on a gallery image in WEEBLY. I know how to change the border color of the gallery images before you click on them. this is arranged in the css like this:

```
/* Gallery ---------------*/

.galleryCaptionHolderInnerBg {
    background:rgba(209,38,38,0.75);
    opacity: 1;
}

.galleryImageHolder .galleryCaptionInnerText {
    text-transform:uppercase;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.157);
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    margin: 30px auto;
    font-weight: 500;
}

.galleryImageHolder {
    border-radius: 3px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.fullImageGalleryCaption {
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 2px; 
    border-radius: 2px;
}
```

i beleive LIghtbox is used for the popup image.... here is the example page where the problem occurs:
http://stanowicki.weebly.com/zwart--wit.html just click on a image and see the ugly white border

Thanks for the help

Comment: the class name is class="fancybox-skin" just set the backgroun color you want in there

Answer (score 0):

the class you are looking for is `fancybox-skin` just try to override it to put the color you want like so

```
.fancybox-skin {

    background-color : #000 !importent;

}
```

Comment: typo with **important**IMO i'm not even sure if you *need* to declare it as important.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
.fancybox-skin {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);/*changed*/
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: #444;
  position: relative;
  text-shadow: none;
}
```